# Raspberry pi not displaying anything

Tags: boot, sd-card

I'm using a rapsberry pi 4 with the original power supply. Everything was working with the pi and then one day I turn it on and it no longer works. When I turn the pi on the red light is constantly on, the green light doesn't turn on at all. I've re-written the SD card with the raspbian OS, still nothing. I've tried turning the pi on without the SD still a blank screen. I don't think it's the HDMI cable because the entire setup was left alone and now it's not working. Also tried it on another monitor and I still get nothing. The hdmi port that the cable is connected to is hdmi0. I've also tried setting the hdmi_mode = 16 in the config.txt and it still doesn't work. Shouldn't the pi show something even when there's no SD card?

Comment: *"Shouldn't the pi show something even when there's no SD card?"* -> Yes, minimally I think you get a multicolored pane of four squares; not sure what else the 4 will show but I think the firmware in the emmc does put out something.   That is, unless the hardware is damaged, of course...

Comment: "That is, unless the hardware is damaged", how does this happen, I don't remember shorting any pins or anything, it just stopped working one day

Comment: Lots of electronic devices just stop working, unfortunately.  Likely all of them would, given enough time, dependent on environmental factors.  We do regularly get reports of that kind of thing here.  If bought less than a year ago, you should be able to make a warranty claim.  If so, insist on a replacement if you can, as they have become difficult and expensive to procure.

Comment: `it just stopped working` ... maybe it was killed by electrostatic discharge when you touched it

Comment: Work through https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=58151 If that fails your Pi is dead.